# Android Bound Service vs Started Service for music app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to dive deep into service architecture.
Just for testing purpose I am creating music app.
Without doubts music should be played in service, but what kind of communication to use ? 
As far as I know service can be bound or started (or both at the same time)

**Firstly**, I need to play/stop/pause/set source...
**Secondly**, I need to notify UI if music player is opened about events like progress, buffering...

Here my thoughts about this.
I think about mixing bound and started service.

As far as song can be set only from UI as well as paused/played/stopped/seek I choose communication with service from UI using binder. (Bound service inside activity and get binder back to communicate with service)

Notifications like track completed, next track , current track position coming from the service. I decided to use `Broadcast receiver` to send such notifications, because it can be multiple interested components.

So my question are

1. What is the best choice of communication (bound or broadcast) for music player service ?
2. How does System knows what kind of service is ? I mean that even if the service is `bound` I need to call `startService` method at first and than bind it. Does it mean that if even one `bindService` method was called it is considered as bound service and it would be killed when `unbind` method is called ?
3. Does `LocalBroadcastManager` make sense in communication with service ? As far as `LocalBroadcastManager` is local for each app, why not to use bound service than ? Global broadcast makes sense in case other apps are interested in events.

Please help to understand this mechanism.

Comment: Did you complete music app? If Yes, how you managed music(play, pause, stop ...)? through Service, Intent Service or something else? I am at your starting point;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Best choice of communication is using both LocalBroadcasts as well as Binder methods as per your requirement. If you want to do something in service from your bound component like activity then you should use binders. If you need to send result back to application you should use LocalBroadcast.

There is one more option available to use messaging. In this case both activity and service use same ibinder hence two way communication is easy. You can send message from activity to service and service to your activity

2. In this point you are wrong about starting bound service. You don't need to call startservice in this case. Just a call of bindservice method is required.

   bindService(new Intent(this, MessengerService.class), mConnection,
               Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

you can bind multiple components to this service. When all of them are unbound then service will be stopped.

3. Yes LocalBroadcastmanagers make sense. Lets say you want to broadcast something in your app. There are 4-5 components that you want to update.How will you achieve this. Hence the use of localbroadcasts is a good feature.

For example lets say there are two services starting from different activities and second service starts its work when first service has done its work. So, only way to achieve this is send a broadcast and second service will be registering for this broadcast. Hence it will receive it.

Comment: Thank you for answer !! I have forgotten about the thing you mentioned in your answer. That communication can biderectional using binder (like fragment and activities using casting to some interface). I thinks if bind service is already used it would be easier and cleaner way to implement this using binder, only one thing if some other component is interested in events it would be better to use LocarBroadcast, am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah.  Services are pretty hard to understand.

There are some things that are easy.  A bound service is *always* started with a `bindService` method.  A started service is *always* started with a `startService` method.  You do *not* need to start a bound service, or bind a started service.

A lot of what follows is gross generalization...

**Started Service**

A started service is nearly useless, unless it is an `IntentService`.  IntentServices are pretty good tools for running asynchronous tasks.  You send them a small bundle of parameters and they go off and do whatever those parameters indicate.  They are like `void` methods in that one expects to use their side-effects, not a return value.

**Bound Service**

A bound service is harder to explain.  Although the metaphor breaks down on careful examination, a bound service something like a singleton factory.  It is, for instance, a way of providing a single object, with is single state, to all of the Activities in a application.  Among its interesting features is that, as long as the service that provided the singleton object is bound, the hosting process is less likely to be killed off.  Note that, the "singleton" object that the bound service provides has little to do with the service that provides it.  Unbinding the service does *not* invalidate it.

Bound services are also the main means of doing inter-process communication, in Android.

**What should you do?**

Well, that's a pretty general question.  Here's a thought.  Putting your music player in a service makes a lot of sense.  If the communication to it is mostly one way -- commands to the service -- there is a chance that you can do it with an `IntentService`.  Until there's a specific reason to do something more complex, an `IntentService` has the advantage of being simpler.

Comment: Thank you for complete answer. Is there any good articles or books to read about internals of services you can suggest ?

Comment: Not the answer you want, I suspect, but I'm writing one right now : http://www.amazon.com/Android-Concurrency-G-Blake-Meike/dp/0134177436/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1454861720&sr=1-1&keywords=android+concurrency  Should be out in the 2nd quarter of this year.